# TypeScript: Return Result of a Promise

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, promise

I am working on a Ionic app that uses Fireface Login with Facebook. For that I followed the docs here: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/Auth-with-Ionic2.md

Almost at the end of the docs you can see the piece of code that does the FB login (using the Native FB App if available):

```
  signInWithFacebook(): firebase.Promise<FirebaseAuthState> {
    if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
      return Facebook.login(['email', 'public_profile']).then(res => {
        const facebookCredential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(res.authResponse.accessToken);
        return firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(facebookCredential);
      });
    } else {
      ...
    }
  }
```

This kind of screws up the return type of the method signInWithFacebook. Actually the method should return the result of the Promise triggered by Facebook.login(...) - but it does return the FacebookLogin-Promise itself which has a different data type.
I'm a bit confused how I can re-model those lines to properly return the Promise created by firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(facebookCredential).

Do you have any hints/ideas?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: havent used the iconic library so dont know what actually you are refferring to. can you explain in a bit more details what you mean by ". Actually the method SHOULD return"

Comment: Return type of signInWithFacebook is firebase.Promise<FirebaseAuthState>. But the return type of Facebook.login() is Promise<FacebookLoginResponse> - which is not compatibale. But the result of the resolved Promise of Facebook.login() would fit to the method definition of signInWithFacebook. And what I try to do is return the result of the resolved Promise (created by Facebook.login()) - and not the Promise itself.

Comment: what about `return firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(res.authResponse.accessToken).then((facebookCredential)=>firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(facebookCredential));` ?

Comment: How would I get to res.authRespon‌​se.accessToken? This is part of the result of the 'outer' Promise (by Facebook-login()) which I somehow cannot find in your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

OK, so here is a solution (or work-around - whatever you want to call it).

What I changed:

- the method signInWithFacebook does return void
- it takes an anonymous function as argument which gets executed when the inner Promise resolves

Here is the code:

```
  signInWithFacebook(success: (FirebaseAuthState) => void): void {
    if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
      Facebook.login(['email', 'public_profile']).then(res =>
        {
          const facebookCredential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(res.authResponse.accessToken);
          firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(facebookCredential).then( fbas => success(fbas));
        }
      );
    }
    else {
      this.auth$.login({
          provider: AuthProviders.Facebook,
          method: AuthMethods.Popup
        }).then(res => success(res));
    }
  }
```

And this is how to call the method:

```
this._auth.signInWithFacebook2(res => {...});
```